# Как отправить Post запрос на js без библиотек?

Tags: javascript

Я хочу отправить сообщение от сообщества вк. Как составить на js пост запрос аналогичный ссылке

https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?v=5.101&access_token=TOKEN&peer_id=ID&message=TESTest&random_id=1

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вроде того

```
var body="v=5.101&access_token=TOKEN&peer_id=ID&message=TESTest&random_id=1";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("post", "https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
    //Do your code
    }
}
xhr.send(body);
```

[XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) это API предоставлемый бразуером для `Ajax` запросов.
Если значения параметров заранее неизвестны, то эти значения нужно кодировать функцией [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)